# How to delete Disabled services from Services.msc

Tags: c#, service

I want to delete my one service written in c# from the services list showing in services.msc.
i am trying to delete it from the command promp by using the below command.

> sc delete servicesName

But it is not deleting and becomes disabled.

Answer (score 4):

If `sc delete` doesn't work you can try delete it via registry.
First use Run and enter `regedit` then go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`.
After that locate the service name in the left pane, right click it and delete. You will see result after rebooting your system.

Comment: What if i don't want to reboot my system?

Comment: Reason for reboot to update the list of services in service manager. So it should work but you may see your service in service manager list.

Comment: I want to remove the service from the service list once i refresh it..But i have to reboot my system..Why it is not refreshing list without rebooting?

Comment: @HenryDisoza, no need to reboot but just close and reopen Service.msc window

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742045.aspx):

> If the service is running or if another process has an open handle to
>   the service, the service is marked for deletion.

So you have to stop your service first:

```
sc stop servicesName
sc delete servicesName
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that the service must be stopped before you delete it to avoid the dreaded `Disabled` until reboot state. If you are already in that state the only way out is to reboot. So let's avoid that next time.

In practice, there seems to be some difference in how `sc.exe stop` works compared to `net stop` where using sc doesn't always result in a clean delete. Using the net command always does.

You also need to give it a little time between commands.

Here is an example NSIS installer script that works for me in practice.

```
  nsExec::ExecToLog "net stop $\"${Title}$\""

  Sleep 333

  nsExec::ExecToLog "sc.exe delete $\"${Title}$\""
```